# Is it reliable to use TensorFlow (ML in general) to classify baggage bag tags based on the presence of a green stripe?

Tags: classification, tensorflow, image-classification

The images are identical except for the presence of the stripe on the side.
I am trying to use a classify the images into 2 classes: greenStripe, noGreenStripe.

I tried to use tensorflow retrain with a small dataset (~40 pictures in each class and batch size of 8) but the results where really bad. I am afraid to commiting to training using more data as it is time consuming.

What do you suggest? Is there a better approach or does the problem lie in the small training dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- Bags are in free/unconstrained environment
- You are actually looking for the bar-codes in the tags

I propose the following pipeline:

[image]

#### 1 - Detect bags by using a [pre-trained YOLOv3](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) model

#### 2 - Detect Tags

- Create a Tag Detector, ideally using rotation invariant features (such as HOG) with your 40 tag images dataset. You can perform data augmentation (rotation and scaling should be enough) to increase your dataset size.
- You can also use Image registration to do feature-based matching ( see [handouts](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/handouts.html) for classes 12,13 and 14)

#### 3 - Estimate and perform affine transformation to "frontalize" the tags

See the handouts for class 14.

#### Perform bar-code segmentation and then read it

See handouts for class 6.

---

Answer (score 0):

The scientific answer would be, it depends.

In case you are using any kind of Deep net, then 40 images is far too little. 
It might be helpful to describe your problem setting a little bit more in depth.
Are the bags always in the same place, or do they need to be localized first? These kind of details could help other users in their recommendations.

As a first approach, before you try a deep net or any kind of ML I would try a simple baseline first. Do you know what the exact pixel value of your green stripe is? You could then simply check whether this colour is present at all. This is rather coarse, but I would see how far this gets you and it is good to see whether your ML methods can beat this simple baseline. 
Subsequently you could also think of trying to localize the bagtags (in whatever way you like) then cropping it and checking for the presence of this green stripe.

Comment: I am using tensorflow retrain.py (I suppose it uses a deep net). The bagtags are standard (same dimensions colors etc).
The bagtags can be anywhere but we can take closeup pictures.
For localizing the bagtags what strategy do you suggest : The bagtags are rectangles with a barcode in them.

Answer (score 0):

1) Could you upload sample images maybe? It would be easier to decide.

2) Your dataset is very small, training anything significant from scratch will most certainly overfit the model. Take an existing model, that knows what a bag is (e.g. Mask R-CNN) and *finetune* it to your problem by changing the loss function and some architecture.

3) Actual framework should not matter: work with whichever you find convenient.

Comment: This image has a bagtag with the green stripe around it. The plastic wrap is around it is irrelevant. The bagtags either have the green stripe or don't have it/ have it in different color.

Comment: [image](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fscandinaviantraveler.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2Ffacebook_share%2Fpublic%2Fsas-lab-electronic-bag-tag-1140x619.jpg%3Fitok%3DTikIXues&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fscandinaviantraveler.com%2Fen%2Faviation%2Fsas-lab-creates-the-future-of-travel&docid=92NDQeA4Y0c2XM&tbnid=yZHTCPg8g3tg3M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiSzM6n0ZneAhUBESwKHTp0C8IQMwg_KAEwAQ..i&w=1200&h=630&client=firefox-b-ab&bih=733&biw=1440&q=sas%20bagtag&ved=0ahUKEwiSzM6n0ZneAhUBESwKHTp0C8IQMwg_KAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)